# How to install Collabora online on Ubuntu server 20.04 with Raspberry Pi 4 without docker

Tags: server, 20.04, nextcloud

Is there any way for Ubuntu server 20.04 arm64 (raspberry) to install the Collabora Online without Docker?

(Raspberry Pi 4 - Ubuntu Server 20.04 - nginx - nextcloud 23)
Maybe there is nothing in the docker, but I install it in the Collabora Docker?

Comment: It's difficult to understand, do you want to install with or without Docker? I'm guessing without because of the title. But please understand that installing Nextcloud, database, web server, Collabora Online etc. manually might be exceedingly difficult and time-consuming. Installing the stack with Docker is much more manageable, IMHO.

Comment: There is a [guide here](https://community.learnlinux.tv/t/nextcloud-full-setup-implementation-guide/1413) for manual installation. And as another option I've also posted a Docker Compose file for the stack.

Comment: The webserver(nginx), mysql, nextcloud is installed, and work, but I sould be install the collabora online withot docker, but not work

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions for [Linux Packages](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/linux-packages/)? How does it not work for you?

Comment: The problem with this description is that it is only available for arm64 until ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The solution to the problem can be found at the link. You probably just need to rewrite richdocumentscode to richdocumentscode_arm64 in the nextcloud configuration, but I've fixed all the gaps and everything works now!

https://www.c-rieger.de/nextcloud-installationsanleitung

Thank you everyone